# Synchronization of two databases

Tags: database, postgresql

There are two databases. Their structure is identical. But the data in them lives their own lives - they may be identical, may be newer and so on. The databases are located on different servers (server 1 and server 2) and only server 1 can access the database located on server 2.

It is necessary to somehow synchronize them.

In theory, I see it like this:

1. Server 1 makes backup of its own database.
2. Server 1 makes backup of an external database.
3. The resulting two files need to be synchronized somehow.
4. The resulting new file restore on two servers.

But I don't understand how to implement 3 points. Maybe there are some ready-made solutions. I tried looking for something similar in the PostgreSQL documentation, but to no avail.

Comment: One question I have is -- what happens if a change is made to the same row of a table on both Server 1 and Server 2?  Who wins?  Otherwise, sounds like you should use EnterpriseDB XDB (https://www.enterprisedb.com/edb-docs/d/edb-postgres-replication-server/user-guides/user-guide/6.2/toc.html) or BDR (https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/postgres-bdr-2ndquadrant/).  PostgreSQL logical replication (v. 10 and above) is a good option as well.

Comment: @richyen All tables have an `updated_at` field. It is necessary to define a newer record and apply it.

Comment: You will have to write your own code to reconcile the databases according to your specific needs.

Comment: Another question that will orient the answer : how much time both servers can be offline in the same time ? Another question : what is the size of your biggest table? (to have an idea of the complexity)

Comment: @Jaisus Good questions. It is desirable that the servers are not offline. The largest table within 200,000 rows. I think this indicator can be increased to 500,000 rows (for the future).